# Tweets are retrieved from one hashtag - forloop php

Tags: php, api, for-loop, twitter, foreach

I'm trying to print popular tweets from trending hashtags in my country. First, i fetched the trending hashtags then i set the query in the tweets URL to be within the trending hashtags.

The problem is that the tweets are fetched from only one hashtag and it is the least trending one! Also, somehow the tweets are repeated!

How can i fetch the popular tweets from trending hashtags without repetition ?

This is my code:

```
<html>
<?php
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth; 

require_once('twitter-api-php-master/TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
  'consumer_key' => '',
  'consumer_secret' => '',

  'oauth_access_token' => '',
  'oauth_access_token_secret' => '',);
$Saudi_id = 23424938; 
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
/* the url that have the request*/
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json'; 
/*appending values into the url*/
$get_request = '?id=' . $Saudi_id ;
$json_data = $twitter->setGetfield($get_request)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest();
/* converting JSON format into PHP object */
$redeable_data = json_decode($json_data);
/* creating the TRENDS array linked with converted object*/
$trends = $redeable_data[0]->trends; 
// Set here the Twitter account from where getting latest tweets
foreach($trends as $trend){
        # print only the hashtags the starts with #
        if(preg_match("/^#/i",$trend->name)){
        /* prining the name of each hashtag along with the url for navigation as list*/
        $name=$trend->name;
    }
    }
// Get timeline using TwitterAPIExchange
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = "q=".$name."&result_type=recent&count=700";
$tweets = $twitter
  ->setGetfield($getfield)
  ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
  ->performRequest();

$tweets = json_decode($tweets);
echo "<ul>";
if(isset($tweets->statuses) && is_array($tweets->statuses)) {
    if(count($tweets->statuses)) {
        foreach($tweets->statuses as $tweet) {
             echo "<li>";
  echo ($tweet->text);
  echo "</li>";
  // if any image were included within the tweet , print it with size 20%
   if (isset($tweet->entities->media)) {
    $media_url = $tweet->entities->media[0]->media_url;
    echo "<img src='{$media_url}' width='20%' />";
  }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'The result is empty';
    }
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
</html>
```

**Note**: I'm using php to code along with html and TwitterAPIExchange.php library

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
foreach($trends as $trend){
        # print only the hashtags the starts with #
        if(preg_match("/^#/i",$trend->name)){
        /* prining the name of each hashtag along with the url for navigation as list*/
        $name=$trend->name;
    }
    }
```

You are looping through the trending hashtags from most to least trending and keeping only the last as $name - so you end up with the least trending one.   To grab only the first one, do this:

```
$trend = reset($trends); 
$name = $trend->name;
```

If you want to get the tweets for each of the X most popular hashtags do something like this:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) 
        $trend = $trends[$x]
        # print only the hashtags the starts with #
        if(preg_match("/^#/i",$trend->name)){
        /* prining the name of each hashtag along with the url for navigation as list*/
        $name=$trend->name;
        /*get the tweets here inside the loop*/
      $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
      $getfield = "q=".$name."&result_type=recent&count=700";
      $tweets = $twitter
         ->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();

     $tweets = json_decode($tweets);
     echo "<ul>";
     if(isset($tweets->statuses) && is_array($tweets->statuses)) {
        if(count($tweets->statuses)) {
         foreach($tweets->statuses as $tweet) {
         echo "<li>";
     echo ($tweet->text);
     echo "</li>";
     // if any image were included within the tweet , print it with size 20%
     if (isset($tweet->entities->media)) {
        $media_url = $tweet->entities->media[0]->media_url;
         echo "<img src='{$media_url}' width='20%' />";
     }
    }
    }
     else {
    echo 'The result is empty';
     }
   }
   echo "</ul>";
    }
    }
```

Comment: do you know how can i fix this, please?

Comment: If you only want the most popular loop, then only read the first one from $trends - so don't loop through (or only "loop" once)

Comment: I added some code - untested, as I haven't done php in a while but it hopefully is close

Comment: I completely understand your point but how can i make the loop to read every single hashtag? because i applied your code and now it fetches the tweets from the most trending hashtag.

Comment: edited again - the part getting the tweets is all your original stuff.  I only changed the loop at the top

Comment: still not working. I believe there is something wrong with reading each hashtag. Thanks anyway you've done great so far :).